# work flow rule object limit

Tags: workflow, workflowrule

In my org, I have 14 active workflow rules out of 15(one is inactive).
10 workflows on contact object and rest 5 are on different objects below is the image

[image]

But when I check the object limit of Contact object it shows 14 active workflow and 15 total workflows but I have 15 aggregate workflow and only 10 are for contacts not all 15 of them.

[image]

Total workflow rules on contact 
[image]
Can someone please help to understand why the number of workflows on contact object limit are showing 15 instead of 10?

Comment: You've apparently misread the global limits as the limits per a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total active workflow rules per object-50

> (This limit applies to any combination of active processes and
>   workflow, assignment, auto-response, and escalation rules.)

This means you have 10 workflows and may be 5 process builder.

Total workflow rules per object-500

> (This limit applies to any combination of workflow, assignment,
>   auto-response, and escalation rules, both active and inactive.)

Reference:-

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits.htm&type=5

Hope it helps you.